# Angularjs Sharing controller between directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

While implementing angularjs directive i have got some issues in sharing controller between directive

i cant access the enterUser directive from the below controller

```
app.directive('entires', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope : {
      user : '='
    },
    require : '^?enterUser',
    template:"<div><b>Time : </b>{{user.name}}  <b>Task :</b> {{user.age}} <a ng-click='delete(user);'><u>Delete Entry</u></a> <br></div>",
    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, enterUserctrl) {
     console.log(ctrl)
    //here i got enterUserctrl undefined..
    // i want like to call delete function from here
    enterUserctrl.delete(user); 


    }

  };
}])
```

here the current working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrlovejs/NQ55Y/)

Comment: You got `undefined` because `div[enterUser]` is not in the parent tree of `div[entires]`.

Comment: Try to `ng-repeat` users in the template of directive enterUser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified your code a little. Two main errors: `enter-user` should wrap `entires` so angular could find it for `require`. And the second is that you need to use `transclude` in your case.

Take a look at the code

```
app.directive('enterUser', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'enter-user.html',

        controller: function ($scope) {

            $scope.addToList = function (name, age) {
                if (typeof $scope.userName != 'undefined' && typeof $scope.userAge != 'undefined') {
                    $scope.nameList.push({
                        name: $scope.userName,
                        age: $scope.userAge
                    })
                    $scope.userName = '';
                    $scope.userAge = '';
                }
            };

            this.delete = function(user) {
                if (typeof user != 'undefined') {
                    $scope.nameList.pop();
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

#### enter-user.html

```
<div>
    <b>Name: </b>
    <input ng-model='userName' type='text' />
    <br>

    <b>Age  : </b> 
    <input ng-model='userAge' type='text' />
    <br>

    <span class='right'><button ng-click='addToList(userName, userAge);'>Add to List</button></span>

    <!-- insert trascluded content here -->
    <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

#### entires directive

```
app.directive('entires', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            user: '='
        },
        require: '^enterUser',
        templateUrl: "entires.html",
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, enterUserCtrl) {
            scope.delete = function(user) {
                enterUserCtrl.delete(user)
            }
        }
    };
});
```

#### index.html

```
<div enter-user>
    <b><u>Here is my entries listed </u></b>
    <div ng-repeat="user in nameList">
        <entires user="user"></entires>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEgcXxNQEJI4JznLs0OI?p=preview)

Also your delete function does not work properly. But this is little thing.

Comment: Doesn't work, if you try delete user in the middle, it deletes last one.

Comment: @WildGoat Here is correct version of the code using splice to delete items: http://plnkr.co/edit/U8eBda8bKVgfwoRRFKkp?p=info

Answer (score 1):

From your code the `<div enter-user></div>` is separated from second directive `entires`.

If `entires` directive uses *parent* directive `enterUser` the structure I think should be something like:

```
 <div enter-user>
      <div ng-repeat="user in nameList track by $index">
          <entires user="user"></entires>
      </div>
   </div>
```

You can see [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZrX3/24/) demo that might help you.

> ^ – Will look for the directive on parent elements, if not available on the same element.

From child directive:

```
require : '^?enterUser',
```

If we remove `?` we will get an error that parent directive not found. So this is a issue.